# downloading files from a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to add a drop-down menu displaying files located in directory (uploads) and have users selecting (a) file(s) to download to their local machine. 
I have use the following PHP code to populate an array and a pseudo HTML code to generate the drop-down menu, which is supposedly passing the name of the selected file to a JavaScript which is to force the browsers to download the file. 
There two issues here, 1- it seems the name of the selected file (line 15) is not passed to the JavaScript (line 23); 2- Even if I do force the file name (line 27), I receive a permission error preventing the file from being downloaded.
Since I am totally inexperienced in coding, any help I can get, is highly appreciated.

PHP:

```
$dirname = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..' . '/uploads');

$files = array();  
$dir = opendir($dirname);  
while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
{  
if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && !is_dir($file)) 
 {     
 $files[] = $file;       
 }     
}  
closedir($dir);    
sort($files);  
$files[] = 'Select a document to download';  
echo '<select name="download" class="pickupzone" onchange="myDownload(this.value)">';   
for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)   
{    
  echo '<option value="" selected="selected">' . $files[$i] . '</option>';    
}  
echo '</select>';  
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myDownload(val)  
{  
 if (val == 'Select a document to download') return;   
  var link = document.createElement("a");  
  link.download = val;  
  link.href = '../uploads/';  
  link.click();  
  window.alert('downloading: ' + link + link.download);

</script>
```

Comment: This seems over-complicated. Why not just display the files as a list of hyperlinks (<a href="...) instead of making the user choose from a drop-down and then click again? It would remove the need for any javascript as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one:

```
$dirname = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..' . '/uploads');
$files = array();  
$dir = opendir($dirname);  
while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
{  
   if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && !is_dir($file)) 
   {     
      $files[] = $file;       
   }     
}  
closedir($dir);    
sort($files);  
$files[] = 'Select a document to download';  
echo '<select name="download" class="pickupzone" onchange="myDownload(this.value)">';   
for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)   
{    
    echo '<option value="' . $files[$i] . '" selected="selected">' . $files[$i] . '</option>';    
}  
echo '</select>';  
?>
```

Here i just update the option tag in for loop. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you Eshu, it did address passing the filename to JavaScript. Now I have to resolve the permission error that prevents the file from being downloaded. Thanks again.